# Does receiving copy of dress code mean offer is imminent?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, hiring, process

Had an interview with an company, I feel like it went well. At the end of the interview she gave me a copy of the dress code but she said she would give me a call .
Would giving a candidate an copy of the dress code typically mean they got the job?

Comment: Not necessarily but it is a good sign that you have a high chance of getting it. At least you are one of the top contenders. If they did not see you in this position, they wouldn't bother handing you a workplace document.

Comment: Until they contact you with a written offer including salary and start date -- and you have agreed to it -- you do not have the job.

Comment: I had the interview on Monday would it be wrong for me to call them Thursday and ask how my intervieing progress is going?

Comment: Did she indicate when she would give you a call by? Don't call before that deadline.

Comment: Could mean a million things. Jobs generally like to say outright, "Start on date X" rather than being cryptic and hope you show up one day for work. It wouldn't hurt to say to the interviewer, "Does this mean I have the job?"

Comment: I would imagine giving a candidate a copy of the dress code would mean she had spare copies and was too lazy to throw them into dustbin (AmE: trashcan) herself.

Comment: Make sure you read the dress code, and if you are invited for another interview, adhere to it. She may have been dropping you a hint.

Answer (score 8):

There is only one thing that indicates that you've got the job and that's a job offer, and that ultimately **needs to be in writing**. I'm not speaking generally, I'm saying literally that you should only trust an actual job offer as an indication that you have a new job to accept.

Most people here can tell stories about how they were told they had a job verbally or given very clear indications that any reasonable person would believe meant that the job was theirs but the offer never materialized or were rejected outright.

This might seem pessimistic but there is always something that can go wrong before an actual offer is in hand so until that happens, don't do anything rash, don't start telling people what's coming because that could have negative consequences if it turns out to be not the case.

Comment: And even if you do get the offer you may find out the pay is too low, or the work hours are wrong, or the benefits don't start for a year...So you end up rejecting them.

Comment: It's been my experience that you don't have the job until you're sitting at your desk.

Answer (score 1):

I think giving you a copy of the dress code early on is the company's way of having you disqualify yourself (not continue pursuing the job) if you can't adhere to it.  They might apply it very strictly.  I don't get the idea that the dress code bothered you, but we can't assume every applicant's cool with it.  If the dress code is an important value for the business, it's better to lay it out early rather than assuming folks will "snap to it" after being hiring.  It also gives you a heads-up to *consider* having to buy the clothes you'll need.

Still, anything they hand to you says they're interested in you.  But as Christopher Estep has laid out, wait for a formal offer.  If you get only a verbal offer (i.e. they don't volunteer right away to give you a written one), it's best for that you tactfully express your need for the written one.  It'll potentially save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: *after being hired

Comment: I would also take this an indicator the interviewer had not ruled you out at that point, but nothing stronger. Interviewers don't always have the final say and anyway, they may have people they have not interviewed yet who might be stronger candidates than you.  I agree that it could well be an indicator that they are dead serious about the dress code.